# Using browser console with Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'd like to execute some JavaScript function using Selenium Firefox WebDriver.
I've tried to do it with JavascriptExecutor, but it's not the thing I do need, because it allows to execute own, or global functions. But I want to execute some website's functions, which JavascriptExecutor can't reach.
In other words, Does Selenium provide some tool to co-operate with browser console?
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExecutor.executeScript("someCommand(someArguments)");
```

But I end up with someCommand is not defined.
Same code "someCommand(someArguments)" works fine in browser's console.

Comment: Well, if `someCommand` is global, you'd be able to do it, if not - you can't do it. It's pretty much the same as opening the console and typing stuff there. After all, if a function is out of scope for the JS console in the browser, it'd be out of scope for Selenium.

Comment: Old thread but hope someone sees this. The console is able to execute the command but I am getting a not-defined error when I use JavascriptExecutor. Any ideas on how I can work with this?